# Hi, Im creating a simple program. I just need users input and to continue the flow of the program (using if,else and while loops)

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

```
playerChoice = input("Do you want to play more (y/n) ? ").lower()
while playerChoice != "y" or "n":
    playerChoice = input("Do you want to play more (y/n) ? ").lower()

if playerChoice == "y":
    nextWord = int(input("Well then, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? "))
    while nextWord != 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
        nextWord = int(input("Well then, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? "))
    if nextWord == 1:
        print("I'm 1")
    elif nextWord == 2:
        print("I'm 2")
    elif nextWord == 3:
        print("I'm 3")
    elif nextWord == 4:
        print("I'm 4")
elif playerChoice == "n":
    print("Thanks for playing, Bye!")
    exit()
```

So basically, this program woud'nt run pass my (Do you want to play more (y/n) ? ) statement, its keep repeating it no matter the users output. How do I fix it?

This is all im getting:

```
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
  Do you want to play more (y/n) ?
```

Comment: `while playerChoice not in ["y", "n"]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `playerChoice != "y" or "n"` is the same as `(playerChoice != "y") or "n"`.

It checks if `playerChoice != "y"` is true, or if `"n"` is true. And `"n"` will *always* be true, hence the infinite loop.

You need for example `playerChoice not in ["y", "n"]` instead.

Comment: Secondly I would say the indentation is pretty important. Even with the correction you suggest, OP's code will still only run an infinite loop in the first 3 lines. But I guess it might be a typo, otherwise he/she wouldn't have accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

First off your indentation is not correct, the code needs to execute under the while loop. You can set the playerchoice variable to nothing before running the loop and only check if `n` is in the answer, then exit or process the input accordingly depending on the input. Example:

```
playerChoice = ""
while "n" not in playerChoice:
    playerChoice = input("Do you want to play more (y/n) ? ").lower()
    if playerChoice == "y":
        nextWord = int(input("Well then, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? "))
        while nextWord not in [1,2,3,4]:
            nextWord = int(input("Invalid input, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? "))
        if nextWord == 1:
            print("I'm 1")
        elif nextWord == 2:
            print("I'm 2")
        elif nextWord == 3:
            print("I'm 3")
        elif nextWord == 4:
            print("I'm 4")
    elif playerChoice == "n":
        print("Thanks for playing, Bye!")
        break
```

Test:

```
Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
Well then, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? 2
I'm 2
Do you want to play more (y/n) ? y
Well then, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? 5
Invalid input, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? 4
I'm 4
Do you want to play more (y/n) ? n
Thanks for playing, Bye!
```

I changed the nextword loop to only check if the inputs 1,2,3,4 is being entered by putting the values in a list and checking if the input is in that.

Answer (score -1):

Your code was not properly made

```
playerChoice = input("Do you want to play more (y/n) ? ").lower()
while True:
    if playerChoice == "y":
        nextWord = int(input("Well then, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? "))
        while nextWord not in [1,2,3,4]:
            nextWord = int(input("Invalid! Please select only one of these options, which word would you like to go next (1/2/3/4) ? "))
        if nextWord == 1:
                print("I'm 1")
        elif nextWord == 2:
            print("I'm 2")
        elif nextWord == 3:
            print("I'm 3")
        elif nextWord == 4:
            print("I'm 4")
    elif playerChoice == "n":
        print("Thanks for playing, Bye!")
        exit()
    playerChoice = input("Do you want to play more (y/n) ? ").lower()
```

Comment: What changes did you make? Why did you make those changes? How does your code solve the problem? And what was the actual problem in the question? Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).